# Boto: Uploading a generated html string to Amazon s3

Tags: python, boto

I need to generate HTML files on the fly and save them to selected folder of the bucket and received the url.

I have seen [uploading a file boto](http://ferrouswheel.me/2009/12/upload-a-file-to-s3-with-boto/) however I want to dynamically generate string of HTML a file on amazon s3 without actually saving the file to my local computer.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example you cite uses the `set_contents_from_filename` method of the Key object to upload content to S3 from a local file.  Alternatively, you could use the `set_contents_from_string` method of the Key object to upload content from your generated string of HTML.  The first argument is the string to upload rather than a path to a file.